# ERROR TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__(...).show().revolution is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular11, revolution-slider

I am learning Angular. I am trying to integrate Revolution Slider in Angular 11 WebSite. Script section of my `angular.json` file is like below.

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "src/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "src/assets/js/modernizr.custom.js",
    "src/assets/js/gmaps.js",
    "src/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js",
    "src/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js",
    "src/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js",
    "src/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.carousel.min.js",
    "src/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.kenburn.min.js",
    "src/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.migration.min.js",
    "src/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js",
    "src/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js",
    "src/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js",
    "src/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js",
    "src/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.video.min.js",
    "src/assets/js/dlmenu.js",
    "src/assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js",
    "src/assets/js/mixer.js",
    "src/assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js",
    "src/assets/js/owl.carousel.js",
    "src/assets/js/slick.js",
    "src/assets/js/jquery.appear.js",
    "src/assets/js/theme.js"              
]
```

I installed jQuery using below code.

```
npm install jquery --save
```

My component is like below

**rev-slider.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-rev-slider',
  templateUrl: './rev-slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rev-slider.component.css'
    ]
})
  

export class RevSliderComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {

        ($(this.element.nativeElement) as any).show().revolution({
            //more text here
        });
    }
}
```

I added this component in parent component like below

```
<app-rev-slider></app-rev-slider>
```

I am getting below error in console.

```
ERROR TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__(...).show().revolution is not a function
```

[image]

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? You don't need any JQuery to show or hide an Angular  component, if this is your intention.

Comment: @Lynx242 Thanks for your reply. I am trying to integrate Revolution slider.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

to

```
declare var $;
```